# REPLACE() in Postgres can't replace data

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, procedure

I'm new in postgres, I'm creating a procedure to rename table constraint names using the REPLACE(). If I test all the variables in this procedure the data is there and if I replace it manually it can. The problem is when this procedure is running the constraint name doesn't change.

```
create or replace procedure public.rename_existing_constraint_table(in table_name text, in date_now text, in list_constraint text[])
    as $$ declare 
        const text;
        table_rename text;
    begin
        table_rename := (select concat(table_name, '_', date_now));
        if array_length(list_constraint, 1) >= 1 then
            foreach const in array list_constraint loop
                execute 'alter table if exists ' || table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || const || ' to ' || replace(const, table_name, table_rename);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end $$
language plpgsql;
```

duplicate error because the data was not successfully renamed, it should be
**app_devlogdetail_pkey to app_devlogdetail_20221214_pkey**

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "app_devlogdetail_pkey" already exists
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "alter table if exists app_devlogdetail_20221214 RENAME CONSTRAINT app_devlogdetail_pkey to app_devlogdetail_pkey"
PL/pgSQL function rename_existing_constraint_table(text,text,text[]) line 10 at EXECUTE
```

I have tried running the REPLACE() outside the procedure and it runs normally and the data can be changed, but when it is run inside the procedure to be executed the REPLACE() can't changed data. How to make the REPLACE() can run and the data can be changed or is there some other way around it?

Comment: I think the problem is your change the table name from "app_devlogdetail" to "app_devlogdetail_20221214" then you want the primary key change from "app_devlogdetail_pkey" to "app_devlogdetail_20221214_pkey" . You can do that will concat.

Comment: @jian i have used concat in "table_rename" variable, you can look at my code in the question

Comment: basically, you replace function is like `SELECT REPLACE ('app_devlogdetail_pkey','app_devlogdetail_20221214','app_devlogdetail_20221214'||'_' || 'pkey');` which will return `app_devlogdetail_pkey`. That seems to be the root of your probelm.

Comment: I replicated your error in here: https://dbfiddle.uk/omuMReuF

Comment: yes I understand. after I double-checked my code, it turned out that there was an error in the "table_name"  variable, the "table_name " variable should have been filled with the table name before it was changed "app_devlogdetail", not after it was changed "app_devlogdetail_20221214". Thank you @jian